AWS Access Key usage by EKS
Every 5 minutes a series of AWS EKS API calls are made by the EKS cluster

I don't have a problem with these calls as it is probably just required for the EKS cluster operation.
However, the AWS Access key in use by these API calls is owned by a person who originally created the cluster. If this person was to leave the company, their account and all API keys would of course be invalidated. How can this be changed?

Hmmm that shouldn't be a thing in normal operation, the cluster if configured correctly shouldn't use a users Access key.
Based on the API calls being made, my guess is that the user setup ClusterAutoscaler (or some other app) using there own keys. the setup guide https://github.com/kubernetes/autoscaler/blob/master/cluster-autoscaler/cloudprovider/aws/README.md#Auto-discovery-setup. has instructions on this.  Use  kubectl get secrets to see if there secrets added to the cluster that match those in guide.
